# Cleaning scanned grayscale images with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-scanner

I have a lots of scans of text pages (black text on white background).

My usual approach is to clean those in Gimp using the Curves dialog using a pretty simple curve with only four points: 0,0 - 63,0 - 224,255, 255,255

This makes all the greyish text pitch black plus makes the text sharper and turns most of the whitish pixels pure white.

How can I achieve the same effect in a script using ImageMagick or some other Linux tool that runs completely from the command line?

`-normalize` or `-contrast-stretch` don't work because they operate with pixel counts. I need an operator which can make the colors 0-63 (grayscale) pitch black, everything above 224 pure white and the rest should be normalized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Color Modifications page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/) shows many color manipulation algorithms by ImageMagick.

In this specific case, two algorithms are interesting:

- [-level](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#level)
- [-sigmoidal-contrast](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#sigmoidal)

`-level` gives you perfect black/white pixels near the ends of the curve and a linear distribution between.

The sigmoidal option creates a smoother curve between the extremes, which works better for color photos.

To get a similar result like in GIMP, you can try to apply one after the other (to make text and black areas really black).

In all cases, you will want to run `-normalize` first (or even [-contrast-stretch](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#contrast-stretch) to merge most of the noise) to make sure no black/white levels are wasted. Without this, the darkest color could be lighter than `rgb(0,0,0)` and the brightest color could be below pure white.

Comment: I successfully converted a large set of Doré Woodcuttings, scanned, with `for file in *; do mogrify -normalize -level 27%,76% $file; done`. I found the 27% and 73% by experimenting with the curves-tool in the gimp.

Answer (score 1):

[[magick-users] Curves in ImageMagick](http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2007-February/019119.html)

The first link in that archived message is a shell script that I think does what you're looking for.

Comment: The link is dead, use an archived version https://web.archive.org/web/20111013185834/http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2007-February/019119.html

Comment: The current version of those scripts can be found at https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/

Comment: Since the script does not explain how to use the parameters, could you please elaborate?